# Syntax for Initializing Array of Anonymous Objects

Tags: vb.net, syntax, initializer

You can [initialize an anonymous object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385125.aspx) like this:

```vb
Dim cust = New With {.Name = "Hugo", .Age = 23}
```

And you can [initialize a collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293617.aspx) like this:

```vb
Dim numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Dim names As New List(Of String) From {"Christa", "Brian", "Tim"}
```

But can you initialize an array of anonymous object **with syntax support**

You can do it like this, but `custs` will just be a plain `object`:

[image: Dim custs = { New With {.Name = "Hugo", .Age = 23}, New With {.Name = "Boss", .Age = 32} }]

You can do it like this, but each item in `custs` will just be a plain `object`:

[image: Dim custs As New List(Of Object) From { New With {.Name = "Hugo", .Age = 23}, New With {.Name = "Boss", .Age = 32} }]

How can I initialize a list/collection/array such that I can access the full power of the collection and also the properties of the anonymous object type inside

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the option for **Inferred Typing** turned off.  This could be illustrated by a simpler example where initialing an object without declaring its type first resulted in a plain, boring object.

[image: = vs. As assignment]

To resolve this, you can turn On Inferred Typing with the option statement:

```vb
Option Infer On
```

Now our simple date example should work:

[image: Dim x = New DateTime]

Finally, just make sure you compile the the code once because anonymous objects are actually implemented as hidden classes behind the scenes.

[image]

Comment: This is called "inferred typing" (identical to using "var" in C#) and there is no requirement to use Option Strict Off.  Dynamic typing is using Option Strict Off and declaring as Object (identical to using "dynamic" in C#)..